# Corona SDK - How to implement a path to an object with physics

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm currently trying to make a top-down based game using Corona SDK.
Basically what I wanna do is, make enemies move straight to the center of the map. It is easy to do it with `transition.to()` but when I do that, the objects lose their physics until they reach their destination.

I was wondering, is there anyway to make the objects move like `transition.to()` but without using it? Because I really want my objects to hit obstacles on their way when they're trying to get to the center of the map.

About the game scenario:
Its like a tower defense game, there is a object in the middle(Castle) there is need to be hitted by other objects(enemies) that respawn randomly from the sides.

Here is some code:

```
function spawnEnemy()
    for i=1,numberEnemies do
        enemy = display.newImage("enemy.png")
        physics.addBody(enemy,"dynamic")
        enemy:addEventListener("tap",enemyKill)
        enemy.gravityScale = -0

        if math.random(2) == 1 then
            enemy.x = math.random(-100, -10)
            enemy:setLinearVelocity(50,0)
        else
            enemy.x = math.random (display.contentWidth + 10, display.contentWidth + 100)
            enemy:setLinearVelocity(-40,0)
        end
            enemy.y = math.random(display.contentHeight)
            --enemy.trans = transition.to(enemy, {x=centerX, y=centerY, time=5000,onComplete=hitCastle})

    end
    timer.performWithDelay( 10000, spawnEnemy, 0 )
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the linear velocity of the enemy so that the enemy heads towards the center.  Once the enemy collides with the castle, you can remove the enemy object from the scene.  In order to do this, you must calculate the vector between two points (the enemy and the center) and then multiply both the X and Y values of the vector by the speed you would like the enemy to move.

```
Enemy position = (EnemyXPos, EnemyYPos)
Center Position = (CenterXPos, CenterYPos)
Velocity Vector = (CenterXPos - EnemyXPos, CenterYPos - EnemyYPos)
```

You then need to normalize the Velocity Vector (Not covered in this answer) which will give you the x and y values of a vector that points from the enemy to the center with a length of 1.

To adjust speed:

```
Adjusted Velocity Vector = (NormalizedVelXVal * Speed, NormalizedVelYVal * Speed)
```

At this point, you just set the enemies linear velocity equal to the Adjusted Velocity Vector calculated above.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the API for body.

These two links should help you to solve the problem :

[https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/applyLinearImpulse.html](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/applyForce.html)
and
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/applyForce.html